# Is there an offline GPT model I can use to generate narrative reports from excel data based on an existing set of files?

Tags: gpt, recommendation

I have a large excel spreadsheet containing data that I have used to write many narrative reports. Without knowing a ton about the technical side of GPT models it seems like it would be theoretically possible to train a GPT model on the existing data (~750 excel rows and 750 corresponding narrative reports, which have a lot of shared structure but many individual variables that can differ) to generate narrative reports from new spreadsheet entries. The catch is that I have to do this offline (HIPAA protected healthcare data).

Is something that could be done with any existing offline, open source GPT software? Or something a motivated but novice individual could adapt from existing offline, open source GPT software?

I have looked at the documentation for privateGPT (https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT) which leads me to believe something like what I'm describing is plausible (although privateGPT appears strictly geared toward answering narrow queries as opposed to generating larger blocks of text).

Answer (score 5):

You can try Langchain library [1]. It's a powerful library to build applications with LLM.

it supports many LLMs integrations[2] along with vector store DBs integrations [3] [4] and many more (i.e agents, embeddings)

You can load your excel file along with other files , split embed and store everything in vector-store DB, then choose local LLM and integrate both to get a Q&A on your data.

1. https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/introduction.html
2. https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms
3. https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/vectorstores/
4. https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/

Comment: thank you for your detailed response and the provided links.  I think if I spend enough time with the documentation I may be able to figure this out, but is anyone aware of any other beginner level resources or tutorials that might help an amateur get going with something like this?

Answer (score 5):

Huggingface maintains [a leaderboard of open LLMs evaluated on various metrics](https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard).

Currently, [Meta's LLaMA 2](https://ai.meta.com/llama/) (and fine-tunings of it) is the most capable LLM that you can run locally. Getting access to the weights does require filling in a form, but appeared to be accepted automatically.

---

To have it generate a narrative report from a row, you could either:

- Include a few examples in the prompt itself before giving the new row you want to generate one for, such as:

  ```
  [Row 1]
  Report: [Narrative report 1]

  [Row 2]
  Report: [Narrative report 2]

  [Row 3]
  Report:
  ```
- Fine-tune the model with [parameter-efficient fine-tuning methods](https://github.com/huggingface/peft), in particular LoRA. [This repostory](https://github.com/tloen/alpaca-lora) contains code for using LoRA on LLaMA with (high-end) consumer hardware.

  This could allow it to be tuned based on all 750 of your available row-report pairs rather than just what would fit into the prompt.

Comment: - Thanks for the excellent answer!
- To the OP: from your description, it seems your task is not complicated. Sounds almost like substituting field values in a template (and maybe doing some rewording). So maybe you'll be able to do with few-shot prompting (the first bullet of what @SirBenet wrote), and won't need fine-tuning.
- Alternatively, you can use [OpenAI fine-tuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning), which is available only with simpler models (Ada, Babbage, Curie, Davinci) but I think these should be enough for your purposes

Comment: @vladimir-alexiev Bit of both actually- I've been using very clunky VBA field merge scripts for a while, but I am definitely writing and rewriting a lot of narrative text around data patterns that are fairly predictable (but too variable and cumbersome to code in excel/vba).